# Custom jena-json writer

Tags: json, jena, writer

I'm creating a web apllication and i want to load a json file to a visualization library. the thing is the json file needs to be in a certain format. 
I'm using jena to get data in a json file that is in the TALIS format. How can i get the data writen in a custom format?Is it easier to first get them in talis and then transform them or get them in the desired form from the beginning?
I'd appreciate every possible help!

Answer (score 0):

You don't say how you are serving your data to the client-side JavaScript application. I'm going to take a guess, and assume you are using [Jena Fuseki](http://jena.apache.org/documentation/serving_data/#running-a-fuseki-server) to serve the data. If that's not a correct guess, you'll need to update the question to be more precise about your setup.

I don't think that Fuseki currently supports pluggable writers. So your best solution would be to apply a transformation in the client-side JavaScript to turn the JSON you get from the server into the format that's needed by the visualisation library. I've done this myself in a number of rich-client applications that consume RDF data. I usually find that I would need to apply client-side transform code in any case - often it's not just a difference in the format of the JSON, but also that you need to project some slice or aggregation of the data that's just easier to express in JavaScript rather than in SPARQL or equivalent.